# why (okfn) function is reqiuerd in the handler function of IP_PRE_ROUTE hook

Tags: c, module, hook

```
static unsigned int pkt_enter(unsigned int hooknum,
                    struct sk_buff *skb,
                    const struct net_device *in,
                    const struct net_device *out,
                    int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
```

The above is a function handler declaration of network hook module which uses NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING hook to capture data. I dont understand why we need the last argument (*okfn) function pointer.

please any one tell me a situation where this parameter is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Net Filter Facility](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~westall/853/notes/netfilter.pdf):

> Even though a hook is passed a pointer to the “okfn” a typical hook
>   will never invoke it, because that would prevent other hooks from
>   inspecting the packet. The OK function is normally invoked by the
>   netfilter code after all hooks have processed the packet.

But see this short [thread](http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2000-January/003173.html).